# How do I formulate a for in loop in R where I may want to loop zero times?

Tags: r, for-loop, idioms

I want to loop over a range of numbers from `1:n`, when `n` is the length of vector `v` in R. Usually, I would use the `for (i in 1:length(v))` syntax, but this fails when `n == 0`.

What is the idiomatic way to do this loop? At the moment I do the followin, but it seems a little ugly:

```
# This is in my standard library
rng <- function(n)seq(from=1, to=n, length.out=n)

# Now when I come to the for loop:
for(i in rng(length(v))){
   print(paste("I ate", i, "kg of brocolli today"))
}
```

And yes, I know its better to vectorise, but there are situations when vectorisation isn't possible or would require so much extra work that it is much harder to read the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be better to use `seq_along`:

```
> v <- letters[1:3]
> for (i in seq_along(v)) print(c(i, v[i]))
[1] "1" "a"
[1] "2" "b"
[1] "3" "c"
> 
> v <- numeric(0)
> for (i in seq_along(v)) print(c(i, v[i]))
```

Comment: Also, `seq_len (0)` gives a vector of length 0 (in case you have a variable holding the limit, instead of a vector to loop over).